# Define different paths by environment in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using two different Rails App to manage photo uploads. So I need to put folder somewhere outside each app and let them to manage it. Paperclip lets to set custom path, but how to make it different for my `development environment` and `production`?

```
has_attached_file :file, 
  :styles => { 
    :full => {
      :geometry => "900x900",
      :quality => "93"
    }
  }, 
:default_url => '',
:path => "/media/Websites/rails/uploads/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", # development path
:url  => "/system/uploads/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also read it from the shell environment which allows configuration without changing the application.

```
:path => ENV['PAPERCLIP_PATH']
```

There is a good writeup on [12factor](http://12factor.net/config) explaining the benefits of this approach

Comment: I add to this answer also this: http://direnv.net/ it will help a lot in this case

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Rails.env.production?` method, like this:

```
:path => Rails.env.production? ? 'production_path' : 'development_path'
```

Answer (score 0):

I like you put variables like this in the Application's config file.

in `config/application.rb`, insert this config line:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # this is the bacon
    config.paperclip_path = 'your/development/path'
  end
end
```

and in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # First, check maybe you'll want to override this in a specific environment
  config.paperclip_path = ENV['PAPERCLIP_PATH'] || '/your/production/path'
end
```

Then, all you have to do is change your `has_attached_file`'s path parameter to:

```
:path => "#{MyApp::Application.config.paperclip_path}/uploads/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
```